# use '&' to create a pointer to member error

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to c++. I'm doing a tutorial question regarding inheritance. I got this error "*'Box::getVolume': Non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member*". Since I'm relatively new, I don't understand what is needed to fix it. This is my code.

Rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle {
private:
   int length;
   int width;

public:
   Rectangle();
   void setR(int, int);
   int getLength();
   int getWidth();
   int getArea();
   void displayR();     
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(){}

void Rectangle::setR(int l, int w) {
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

int Rectangle::getLength() {
    return length;
}

int Rectangle::getWidth() {
    return width;
}

int Rectangle::getArea(){ 
    return length*width;
}

void Rectangle::displayR() {
    cout<<"Length: "<<getLength()<<endl;
    cout<<"Width: "<<getWidth()<<endl;
}
```

Box.h

```
class Box : public Rectangle {
private:
   int height;

public:
   Box();
   void setBox(int);
   int getHeight();
   int getVolume();
   void displayB();

};
```

Box.cpp

```
Box::Box(){ }

void Box::setBox(int h){
   height = h;
}

int Box::getHeight(){
   return height;
}

int Box::getVolume(){ 
   return getArea()*height;
}

void Box::displayB(){
   cout<<"Box height: "<<getHeight()<<endl;
   cout<<"Box volume: "<<getVolume()<<endl;
```

Comment: Woops, didn't even see that...

Comment: @bku_drytt that's fine, it's inherited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int getVolume(){ return getArea()*height;}
```

should be

```
int Box::getVolume(){ return getArea()*height;}
```

Although this shouldn't trigger a compiler error (you'll get a linker error though since `Box::getVolume()` remains undefined).

Comment: Oh pardon me I missed that out, will edit the question. My original code does have int Box::getVolume()

Comment: @ChewingSomething Then I suggest to post a full compilable example, since the code otherwise looks correct. How exactly do you use the `getVolume` function?

Comment: Here, I've edited the question with my codes without the main.cpp. 
Well, in my main, I basically created Box b, and called the the getVolume function by using b.getVolume.

Comment: Omg.. My bad. Very very silly mistake. I did not put () when calling the getVolume function.. Thank you so much and I'm really sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @ChewingSomething no problem, you should also learn about constructors and how to set the height by the constructor (and also how to invoke the base constructor to set the lengths).

Comment: Oh I've learnt about that recently. Non-default constructors right? Hehe I haven't implement it in my codings yet. Will definitely give it a try. Thank you! =)